# Can Virtual Fields be used for a rendering style?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, style, attribute-joins, qgis-2.6

In QGIS 2.6, creating a *virtual* field for a layer and adding up 2 integer fields work fine. I get the correct results and I can use that field for styling.

However, when doing a **Joins** with 2 layers and using a *virtual* field to add up an integer column from each layer, the results displayed are correct. But QGIS does not recognise the values when styling.

[image: Virtual field]

When I try to classify this in the Categorized styling option, no data values are recognised.

[image: Styling]

The virtual field tooltip describes:

> "A virtual field will be recalculated every time it is used. Its definition will be saved in the project file. It will not be saved in the dataprovider and therefore its values not be available in other software."

As it won't be saved in the dataprovider, does that mean QGIS is not even able to read the data? Strangely, I am able to **export** the layer, including the virtual field, as a .csv which outputs all the correct results for the virtual field.

Is this a possible bug?

---

**EDIT**:

The [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11545) for this problem has been ***Closed***, although I will wait until the next major version of QGIS to test this.

If anyone can confirm this (with screenshots preferably) then I will happily accept your answer.

Comment: Please open a bug report on https://hub.qgis.org/issues and attach a sample project/data if possible.

Comment: As a work around you can do the calculation that forms the virtual field in the "column" using the expression builder.

Comment: @Vesanto - Thanks buddy! I was aware of that workaround but for the work I am doing, I would rather have the rendering style based on the actual value. You should post your comment as an answer as it is a good workaround, I will upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bug](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11545) has been closed and fixed, tested on QGIS 2.12.3:

[image: Results]